# Component inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rendering

I am working with React.js

I want to use a component x inside app component(app.js) that is inside index.js.

It does not work.
**

```
Error
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of `App`.
```

**

index.js

```
    import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import {SubComponent} from "./components/Subcomponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SubComponent/>
  );
}
```

Subcomponent

```
const HelloWorld = ()=>{ return(<p>Hello World !</p>)}
export default HelloWorld();
```

Subcomponent folder is :

[image]

Comment: You have a typo `export default HelloWorld();` -> `export default HelloWorld;` - this will export the result of `HelloWorld` rather than the component itself. And use it like `import SubComponent from "./components/Subcomponent";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subcomponent:

- needs to export the same name as what's being imported in App - either use the same named import/export in both places, or use default import/export in both places. (You're currently importing a named `SubComponent` but default exporting)
- needs to export a *component*, which is a function, so that it can be called with `React.createElement` inside App. Don't invoke the function yourself.

App.js

```
import {SubComponent} from "./components/Subcomponent";
```

Subcomponent

```
export const SubComponent = () => {
  return(<p>Hello World !</p>)
};
```

Comment: How would I use default export in both places ?

Comment: What does it mean "do not invoke the function yourself" ? on the code

Comment: To use the default: `export default ()=>{ return(<p>Hello World !</p>)}` and `import SubComponent from "./components/Subcomponent";`

Comment: By "don't invoke it" - your `export default HelloWorld();` is invoking it due to the `()`s at the end